# How to fetch top n records for each category

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-python

I have a table like below, placed at [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8330/8)

```
id  empid proj  file  rating
~~  ~~~~~ ~~~~  ~~~~  ~~~~~~
1   1863   G1   file1    1
2   P4645  G1   file2    1
3   P6682  G1   file3    1
4   P6682  G1   file4    1
5   P4645  G1   file5    1
6   P4645  G1   file6    1
7   1863   G1   file7    1
8   1863   G1   file8    1
9   1863   G1   file19   1
10  P6682  G2   file21   1
11  1863   G2   file55   1
12  P6682  G2   file60   1
13  P4645  G2   file85   1
14  P6682  G2   file91   1
15  P4645  G2   file93   1
16  P4645  G3   file95   1
17  P4645  G3   file100  1
18  P4645  G3   file125  1
19  1863   G3   file131  1
20  1863   G3   file150  1
21  P6682  G3   file193  1
21  P6682  G3   file193  1
```

I need an SQL to retrieve top n (say top 2) ratings count from the above table for each category (proj)

Desired OP as below

```
proj  empid  ratings
~~~~  ~~~~~  ~~~~~~~
 G1   1863      4
 G1   P4645     3
 G2   P6682     3
 G2   P4645     2
 G3   P4645     3
 G3   1863      2
 G3   P6682     2
```

Tried to follow the meathod in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results) but could not achive from the table desing i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
select * from 
(select @rn:=if(@prv=Proj, @rn+1, 1) as rId,
@prv:=Proj,
empid, 
stars
from
(SELECT
          starRatings.Proj
        , starRatings.empid
        , count(*) as stars
    FROM achivement as starRatings
    group by starRatings.Proj,starRatings.empid
order by proj, stars desc)a
join 
(select @rn:=0, @prv:='') tmp
)tmp where rid <= 2
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8330/33)**

```
select * from 
(select @rn:=if(@prv=Proj, if(@prvv=stars, @rn, @rn+1), 1) as rId,
@prv:=Proj,
empid, 
@prvv:=stars
from
(SELECT
          starRatings.Proj
        , starRatings.empid
        , count(*) as stars
    FROM achivement as starRatings
    group by starRatings.Proj,starRatings.empid
    order by proj, stars desc)t
join 
(select @rn:=0, @prv:='', @prvv:=0) tmp
)tmp where rid <= 2
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7420a/7)**:

```
| RID | @PRV:=PROJ | EMPID | @PRVV:=STARS |
-------------------------------------------
|   1 |         G1 |  1863 |            4 |
|   2 |         G1 | P4645 |            3 |
|   1 |         G2 | P6682 |            3 |
|   2 |         G2 | P4645 |            2 |
|   1 |         G3 | P4645 |            3 |
|   2 |         G3 |  1863 |            2 |
|   2 |         G3 | P6682 |            2 |
```

Comment: when i add one more record for empid = P6682 and proj = G3 the result of top 2 in G@ will have 3 records but your SQL is showing firsr 2 even if 2ns 3rd are having 2 stars... check her `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7420a/2`

Comment: Check the edit answer have updated the query as per your need...

Comment: There was mistake in the first query it was not returning on the basis of counts have updated it.

Comment: its working fine in workbench. But i will be executing this SQL from python. As you have used SQL variables `@rn,@prv,@prvv` which will give error in python. is there any other alternate like `joins,sub query's`

Comment: Why it will return error ?? Check how to escape such characters in string in python. i don't think it should return error.

Comment: @Meherzak K i will check and update

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
(
  select proj,empid,rating,count(rating)
  from achivement 
  where `proj` =  'G1'
  group by empid
  order by count(rating) desc
  LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
(
  select proj,empid,rating,count(rating)
  from achivement 
  where `proj` =  'G2'
  group by empid
  order by count(rating) desc
  LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
    (
      select proj,empid,rating,count(rating)
      from achivement 
      where `proj` =  'G3'
      group by empid
      order by count(rating) desc
      LIMIT 2
    )
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8330/28)

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: This only works if you know ahead of time all the possible categories.

Comment: @Barmar yup thats true. I have assumed that all the groups are known to the user beforehand :-